# Trying to set up Android Studio on Ubuntu and running into problems

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm going to be developing an app but when I build the default MainActivity (literally no modifications, just opened the project) in order to make sure everything is working correctly I get the following build error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, 
:app:generateDebugSources,        
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, 
:app:compileDebugSources, 
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/cameron/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt''
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/cameron/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt''
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 14.079 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I know that this is most likely a problem with having the right things installed but I'm not sure what is not installed.

Comment: Do you have `/home/cameron/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt` on your machine? If you do, try running it from a terminal window.

Comment: I fixed it. Apparently I had to install some 32bit libraries